# How to remove events from all elements and then restore them in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build an online CSS editor that works with any page in jQuery.

I have 2 modes: the live mode and editor mode.

- When live, user can click on any element and click event is triggered normally.
- When editor mode, I need to prevent all existing events, so user can pick any dom (ex: button or A link)  without triggering the click event.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Add code to where your events are bound that checks if the app is in editor mode, and don't bind them if so.

Comment: It can be ANY existing PAGE.

Comment: So, ANY PAGE on the internet?

Comment: (Assuming this is a browser extension or the like that can run on any arbitrary page) it would probably be easier to place a non-visible overlay on top of the page to prevent clicks from reaching the preexisting page, and use `document.elementFromPoint()` to determining which element the user meant to click on.

Comment: When you sat: "all events" what exactly do you mean? It appears you are just concerned about click events, correct?